# username not saving? or displaying on user profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have an application that allows users to choose a username when signing up - however, when they sign in their username is blank when it should be saved on sign up, and displayed on their profile.

Here's a snapshot of the sign up form:

```
<div class="home-page-m">
    <div class="container">
      <p class="banner-heading">Meet new people and make new friends</p>
      <div class=" col-md-4 col-xs-12 sign-up-form">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Sign Up</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <%= simple_form_for('user', :as => 'user', :url => registration_path('user')) do |f| %>
            <form role="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1"></label>
                <%= f.text_field :username, class: 'form-control', id: 'Email1', placeholder: 'Username', required: true %>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1"></label>
                <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: 'form-control', id: 'Email1', placeholder: 'First Name', required: true %>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1"></label>
                <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: 'form-control', id: 'Email1', placeholder: 'Last Name', required: true %>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1"></label>
                <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control', id: 'Email1', placeholder: 'Email', required: true %>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1"></label>
                <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control', id: 'Password', placeholder: 'Password', required: true %>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1"></label>
                <%= f.text_field :zip, class: 'form-control', id: 'zip', placeholder: 'Zip', required: true %>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Date" style="display:block; margin-bottom:5px; text-decoration: underline;">Date of Birth :</label>
              <div class="row birth-date">
                <%= f.date_select :birthday, {
                  :order => [:month, :day, :year],
                  :start_year => 1950,
                  :end_year => 2004} %>
              </div>
              <div class="clr"></div>
            </div>
              <div class="col-md-12 text-center sign-b">
                <%= f.submit 'Create Account', class: 'btn btn-default creat-event' %>
                <p>By clicking the button you agree to<br>
                  the terms and conditions</p>
                </div>
              </form>
              <% end %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And here's where the username should be displayed in the users profile after signing up:

```
<div class="users_about_fullinfo">
            <h3><%= current_user.name %>  <small>(<%= current_user.username %>)</small></h3>
            <p class="edit-about-text">
              <%= best_in_place current_user, :blurb, activator: ".edit-blurb", nil: 'Click here to add a short blurb (maximum 140 characters)', inner_class: 'form-control', ok_button: 'Save', ok_button_class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs creat-event blurb-ok', cancel_button: 'Cancel', cancel_button_class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs cencel-event blurb-cancel' %>
              <span class="edit-icon edit-blurb"></span>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="clr"></div>
```

Why isn't the username showing up there? Bare in mind, the current_user.name is showing but not the username..

Any help would be awesome, cheers!

**Update: with users controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to profile_path}
        format.json { respond_with_bip(@user) }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render edit}
        format.json { respond_with_bip(@user) }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id]) || current_user
    @questions_for_about = @user.questions.for_about.order('id asc')
    @questions_for_personality = @user.questions.for_personality.order('id asc')
  end

  def edit_profile
    @user = current_user
    @questions_for_about = @user.questions.for_about.order('id asc')
    @questions_for_personality = @user.questions.for_personality.order('id asc')
  end

  def edit_age
  end

  def update_age
    current_user.update_attributes(birthday: params[:user][:birthday])
  end

  def refresh_notifcations
    @new_messages = current_user.new_messages.count
  end

  # disconnect from social networks
  def disconnect
    social = params[:social]
    current_user.disconnect(social)
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def visitors
    @visitors = current_user.recent_visitors.order('visited_at desc')
  end

  def toggle_hidden
    @hidden_user_id = params[:hidden_user_id] # sent to js.erb
    if params[:action_type] == 'hide'
      current_user.hidden_users.find_or_create_by(hidden_user_id: @hidden_user_id)
    elsif params[:action_type] == 'unhide'
      current_user.hidden_users.where('hidden_user_id = ?', @hidden_user_id).first.destroy
    end
  end

  def toggle_blocked
    @blocked_user_id = params[:blocked_user_id] # sent to js.erb
    if params[:action_type] == 'unblock'
      current_user.blocked_users.where('blocked_user_id = ?', @blocked_user_id).first.destroy
    elsif params[:action_type] == 'block'
      current_user.blocked_users.find_or_create_by(blocked_user_id: @blocked_user_id)
    end
  end

  def account_registration
    @hidden_users = User.where(id: current_user.hidden_users.pluck(:hidden_user_id))
    @blocked_users = User.where(id: current_user.blocked_users.pluck(:blocked_user_id))
    @events = current_user.events
    @activities = current_user.activities
  end

  def update_profile_completness
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  def disable_account
    current_user.disable_account
    Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(current_user)
    redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Account was disabled. Sign in to enable it again.'
  end

 private
    # Using a private method to encapsulate the permissible parameters
    # is just a good pattern since you'll be able to reuse the same
    # permit list between create and update. Also, you can specialize
    # this method with per-user checking of permissible attributes.
end
```

AND

**RegistrationsController**

```
    class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :load_zip_codes, only: [:create]

  # GET /resource/edit
  def edit
    render :edit
  end

  # POST /resource
  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)
    if @zip_codes.include?(resource.zip)
     if resource.save
        if resource.active_for_authentication?
          set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
          sign_up(resource_name, resource)
          respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
        else
          set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
          expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
          respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
        end
      else
        clean_up_passwords resource
        respond_with resource
      end
    else
      TempEmail.create(email: params[:user][:email], first_name: params[:user][:first_name],
        last_name: params[:user][:last_name], zip: params[:user][:zip])
      notice = "Sorry #{params[:user][:first_name]}, we are not accepting sign-ups from outside of New York City Metro Area at the moment, however, we will notify you when we launch in your area!"
      redirect_to root_path, notice: notice
    end
  end

  def update
    if params[resource_name][:password].blank?
      params[resource_name].delete(:password)
      params[resource_name].delete(:password_confirmation) if params[resource_name][:password_confirmation].blank?
    end
    # Override Devise to use update_attributes instead of update_with_password.
    # This is the only change we make.
    if resource.update_attributes(params[resource_name])
      set_flash_message :notice, :updated
      # Line below required if using Devise >= 1.2.0
      sign_in resource_name, resource, :bypass => true
      redirect_to after_update_path_for(resource)
    else
      clean_up_passwords(resource)
      render_with_scope :edit
    end
  end

  def account_registration
     @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  end

  def load_zip_codes
    @zip_codes = ['10453', '10457', '10460', '10458', '10467', '10468', '10451', '10452', '10456', '10454', '10455', '10459',
      '10474', '10463', '10471', '10466', '10469', '10470', '10475', '10461', '10462', '10464', '10465', '10472', '10473', '11212',
      '11213', '11216', '11233', '11238', '11209', '11214', '11228', '11204', '11218', '11219', '11230', '11234', '11236', '11239',
      '11223', '11224', '11229', '11235', '11201', '11205', '11215', '11217', '11231', '11203', '11210', '11225', '11226', '11207',
      '11208', '11211', '11222', '11220', '11232', '11206', '11221', '11237', '10026', '10027', '10030', '10037', '10039', '10001',
      '10011', '10018', '10019', '10020', '10036', '10029', '10035', '10010', '10016', '10017', '10022', '10012', '10013', '10014',
      '10004', '10005', '10006', '10007', '10038', '10280', '10002', '10003', '10009', '10021', '10028', '10044', '10128', '10023',
      '10024', '10025', '10031', '10032', '10033', '10034', '10040', '11361', '11362', '11363', '11364', '11354', '11355', '11356',
      '11357', '11358', '11359', '11360', '11365', '11366', '11367', '11412', '11423', '11432', '11433', '11434', '11435', '11436',
      '11101', '11102', '11103', '11104', '11105', '11106', '11374', '11375', '11379', '11385', '11691', '11692', '11693', '11694',
      '11695', '11697', '11004', '11005', '11411', '11413', '11422', '11426', '11427', '11428', '11429', '11414', '11415', '11416',
      '11417', '11418', '11419', '11420', '11421', '11368', '11369', '11370', '11372', '11373', '11377', '11378', '10302', '10303',
      '10310', '10306', '10307', '10308', '10309', '10312', '10301', '10304', '10305', '10314']
  end

private

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    welcome_path
  end

  def after_update_path_for(resource)
    welcome_path
  end


end
```

Comment: You might have forgotten to add `:username` to your user_params in your UsersController, which means on creation the username is not being persisted to your database. Can you please provide controller/model code?

Comment: Is the CSS styling for the `<small>` tag perhaps hindering visibility?

Comment: Cheers! I've updated the original post with the users controller. Hope that helps.

Comment: Check your console to see if that User has a username. run `rails c` and then `User.first` (if it's the first user you've created). Tell me what his username is

Comment: Thanks! Ok just checked and It's nil.

Comment: That means it's not being persisted to DB on creation. Check my answer AS WELL as the Devise docs, as my answer below is the *lazy* way to fix. Now since you've already created the user, you need a temporary fix, in the console run `User.first.update_attributes(username: "foobar_username")` where `foobar_username` is the username you want.

Comment: Your answer was what worked! Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your `Application Controller`. Check the devise docs for the best implementation for your app. You will probably need this for both User create *and* User update if a User is allowed to change his/her username from their account settings.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << [:username]
  end
end
```

Comment: Ah, can't forget to add `before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?`